# Sum values in different rows, and then count where it meets criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to count the number of sales orders where the pallet quantity is greater than 21. The same sales order number can appear on multiple rows, and the pallet count is tied to each line. In my formula it isn't summing up pallet quantity if a sales order appears multiple times. Assuming I need some sort of combo of count and sum?

Criteria: Count # of sales orders where (Customer = Mike) (Sum of Pallet quantity >=22) (Package Type = Case)

Desired result: 2

Current Formula =COUNT(FILTER(SalesOrderNumber!A:A,( (Package Type!C:C="Case")x(Customer!E:E="Mike")x(Pallet Quantity!D:D>=22) )))

```
SalesOrderNumber  ItemNumber    Package Type    Pallet Quantity  Customer  
16590             14590056      Drum             23               Amy
17950             14590033      Case             23               Mike
17806             33202332      Case             10               Mike    
18900             33202332      Case             11               Mike
18900             33202332      Case             11               Mike
```

Comment: In your example data there's only one order that exceeds qty 21 for customer Mike. So expected result would be 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you suspected this is a two step process. You first need to sum up by order, then you can do your COUNTIF function.

[See similar question here for ways to create your summary table and have it stay up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70197995/excel-group-by-duplicate-and-sum-or-average/70198474#70198474)

Then you can do a COUNTIFS function on the summary data like this `=COUNTIFS(E:E,"Mike",D:D,">"&21,C:C,"Case")`